# how to create batch to move files as per date added. ie one file at a time with 60sec delay in-between 2 file transfer

Tags: timedelay

I want to move files from one folder to another with 60sec time delay between 2 file transfer. and it has to be based on 1st come 1st serve (based on time file added to folder).i havent tried anything on this. need help to add time delay based on file added.